# Include restricted external page with custom stylesheet

Tags: php, css, mobile, include, external

I'm working on a project to mobile-optimize a car dealership website. The problem is, we cannot gain direct access to their MySQL database (they don't have an API) to dynamically generate pages.

What I want to do is PHP include their page, even though I get this error:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /home/content/88/8653188/html/campaigns/summumauto/index.php on line 10

Warning: include(http://www.summumauto.com/en/usedcars/listing/details.spy?id=4745209) [function.include]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/content/88/8653188/html/campaigns/summumauto/index.php on line 10

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://www.summumauto.com/en/usedcars/listing/details.spy?id=4745209' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/88/8653188/html/campaigns/summumauto/index.php on line 10
```

And then I want to use my own stylesheet to actively mess around with the page's CSS to properly morph the page to be mobile-friendly.

Is there any kind of workaround to make this possible, or am I completely stuck?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your php settings (php.ini) do not allow to download http websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [allow-url-include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) config option to true so your above code works.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that was it :-)

Comment: I have 0 access to their server and php configuration.

Comment: In that case use cURL library to download the page, as Jon suggested in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [curl functions](http://php.net/curl) to get around the error.

On the otherhand, if you can configure your server, you can allow inclusion (probably file_get_contents over include) of URLs, though that can open up security holes